# What could cause Node's performance to suddenly halve?

Tags: node.js, performance

My application in Node.js has performance tests that are run several times.  Partway through execution speed drops to half the original value:

```
RUN 1: 6604 ms
RUN 2: 6404 ms
RUN 3: 6386 ms
RUN 4: 6392 ms
RUN 5: 12755 ms
RUN 6: 12977 ms
RUN 7: 13124 ms
```

Insignificant changes to the code can push this cliff forwards or backwards, but I can't figure out what the trigger is.

- Node v8.2.1 on OS X.
- Not recreatable when run with Chrome.
- Total memory usage is a constant 60MB, adding forced GC between runs has no effect.
- The task is purely algorithmic (computing Fibonacci sequences in a very convoluted way), there is no disk or network access.

Does anyone recognize the fingerprint of this issue?

I apologize for being unable to provide a minimal example, the issue only started to surface once the application crossed the 4,000 line mark.  And the issue disappears once the application is trimmed back to below 4,000 lines.

Edit: The same test when run in Debian shows an even more dramatic cliff.  Performance drops sharply from 8424 ms to 45212 ms.

Comment: The test input is always the same? All 7 times same input?

Comment: Delete line 32 of your code and you'll be good to go! [mcve]

Comment: @Lazyexpert Yes, it's exactly the same test being run seven times.

Comment: Since you cannot supply an example of the problem code then this is not the platform for your question as anything we say will be strictly a wild guess.

Comment: @Rob I'm happy to entertain wild guesses.  At this point our best theory is that we are somehow poisoning V8's ability to optimize execution and it is dropping down to the level of a no-frills interpreter.  Just hoping that someone else has seen something like this before.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  This is an issue with the version of V8 used by the current version of Node.  As of `v9.0.0-nightly20170607eef94a8bf8/ 07-Jun-2017 20:00` this issue disappears due to a [new version of V8](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/13263) having landed.

To summarize: it's a previously unknown bug in Node.js, but one that's already fixed in the nightlies and will be released as version 9.

Comment: And we haven't a clue what the issue is, what triggers it, when or where it happens. This is why this whole thing needs to be closed. It's an unknown problem with an unknown resolution.

Comment: Just got word from the Node team that they will be back-porting their fix for this into 8.2.x and will land in the next week or two.Thanks for your help on this.